# strip utm_source from url by htaccess then redirect to origin url

Tags: .htaccess

I have issues with URLs of website.
I have check the server and referrers, then see a lot of strange URLs with some addition var added to original. That may effect the SEO and server load to create those pages.

eg: 
Original:

```
xaluan.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=123456

xaluan.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=123987
```

**Someone access my web page by url**

```
xaluan.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=123456&utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter

xaluan.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=123987&utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter
```

**I need one .htaccess that can redirect all 301 URLs which have `utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter` to original one.**

Answer (score 6):

You could try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^((.*?)&|)utm_
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1?%2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

It will drop everything from the Querystring after the first `utm_`.

Comment: great.. i have managed by my code, but it long and not universal.. 
your solution is best .. work on all case 

thank a ton

Comment: Does anyone know if this still accurately tracks the analytics?